# Extend program to implement pipeline with three commands

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, ipc

My current program implements the pipeline "cat /etc/passwd | cut -f1 -d:" using a pipe and fork.
I want to extend it to implement the longer pipeline "cat /etc/passwd | cut -f1 -d:| sort".

Could someone explain how i should go about doing this? I have attempted with no success but know i need to implement another fork and pipe to extend the pipeline.

The current program code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

int main(void)
  {
    int pfds[2];

    pipe(pfds);

    if(!fork()) {       /*only use child process*/
      close(1); /*close normal stdout*/
      dup(pfds[1]); /*make stdout same as pfds[1]*/
      close(pfds[0]);   /*Dont need this (stdin)*/
      execlp("/bin/cat","cat", "/etc/passwd", NULL);
  }
    else{
      close(0); /*close normal stdin*/
      dup(pfds[0]); /*make stdin same as pfds[0]*/
      close(pfds[1]); /*we dont need this (stdout)*/
      execlp("/usr/bin/cut","cut", "-f1","-d:", NULL); 


  }

  int pfds2[2]; 
  pipe(pfds2);

    if(!fork()){
        dup(pfds2[1]);
        close(pfds2[0]);
        execlp("/usr/bin/sort", "sort", NULL);

  }
    else{
      close(pfds2[1]);
  }


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: @n.m. Have just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start from the back end of the pipeline, not the front.

Try doing a fork and exec. The fork will be the cut, and the exec will be the sort:

```
fork -- exec -- sort
  |
fork -- exec -- cut
  |
no fork -- exec -- cat
```